# Btrfs automatically bitrot correction with snapshots?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, raid, btrfs, snapshot

I want to set up a notebook (debian) with **1 SSD** and **1 HDD** each with Luks and Btrfs on it. Because the SSD and the HDD doesn't have the same speed, i don't want to use **Btrfs' Raid-1** on it, but i also **don't want to miss Btrfs' checksumming and autocorrection**.

Now i am thinking about to use the HDD only for storing snapshots from the SSD. In the meantime i've found this https://superuser.com/a/1099181 , the script create the first time an initial read-only snapshot on the source drive (SSD) and later with example `cron`, an daily incremental snapshot with `btrfs send -p` and `btrfs receive`.

**My questions now:** If the SSD get some troubles for example **bitrot errors**, will and how will i know that this happens? I dont think that Btrfs on the SSD will automatically correct this errors the next time when i make an snapshot and use `btrfs send -p` with `btrfs receive`, because it is simply no **Raid-1**, am I right?

Btw, snaps on the same notebook but different drive aren't my (full) backup strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, learning BTRFS now. I know it is an old post, but try to answer it anyways.

According to [some mailing list](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg62738.html) you can use DUP and RAID1 on a single disk, so if you don't mind the half space it is possible to use your SSD and keep auto data correction. Another way to buy another SSD, which I did.

If you don't want to give up half of your SSD space or more money, then some of the errors can be fixed and others can't without redundancy. You can try [`btrfs check --repair`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfsck) if you have filesystem errors. To detect data rot, you need to use [`btrfs scrub`](https://superuser.com/a/928475/105936), which verifies the crc32 checksums and it displays in the status message whether it found uncorrectable errors. You can find the affected files with [`dmesg`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351735/126217). You can restore the corrupted files manually using your backup. I think it is possible to write a script for this. Still no idea how snapshots will be affected by a file replacement, I suspect they will contain the old corrupted version. I'll post a [question about that part](https://superuser.com/questions/1263600/questions-about-btrfs-data-corruption-and-snapshots).

Comment: The best solution realy would be to use a second SSD with the same speed. HDDs are slow and consume much more energy. Thanks for your answer, and also for your written question! The answers are great!